# JQGrid Resize issue

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I recently started using JQGrid in an app I am developing at work. However, I am having some problems with resizing it on window resize.

The JQGrid is placed inside a table column which is set to 25% of its parent container. When i expand the window, the JQGrid expands correctly, but when I shrink it, it does not shrink proportionately to the parent container ie the JQGrid is more than 25% of its parent.

If someone could give me some input on why this is happening?

Here is my code:

```
    <div id="main_body">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="criteriacolumn" class="column">
                    <table id="list"></table>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

The css:

```
     #main_body{
     border: 1px solid black;
     display: table;
     width: 100%;
     }

     .row{
     display: table-row;
     }

    .column{
    display: table-cell;
    }

    #criteriacolumn{
    border:1px solid red;
    width: 50%;
    min-width: 200px;
    }
```

The js:

```
    $("#list").jqGrid({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/Customer/rest/customers/cust",
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: "GET",
    colNames: ["ID", "CU#","Name"],
    colModel: [
        { name: "custId"},
        { name: "custNbr" },
        { name: "rptName", align: "right" },
    ],
    rowNum:300,
    autowidth:true
    scrollOffset:false
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setGridWidth property to reset the grid size based in parent control width. Perform this action in the window resize event.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    var gridWidth = $('#criteriacolumn').width();
    if (gridWidth > 0) {
        $("#list").setGridWidth(gridWidth);            
    }
});
```